# Cannot find symbol- method newString(char[],int,int) error?

Tags: java, arrays, string, constructor, character

This is my code `String sub= newString(ara,s,4);`

Where `s` is an `integer` variable and `ara` is a `character array`.

Comment: I suggest you use code completion in your IDE and it will help you type less and avoid error like this.

Answer (score 2):

change `String sub= new string(ara,s,4);` to `String sub= new String(ara,s,4);`

[**String**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is a class and all classes start with capital letter.

Comment: I typed it wrong in question.. I have edited it now..

Comment: @Ajay it should be new String